# update vue chart-js y axis max value without re rendering entire chart

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I am working on a project where I am implementing some charts from the Vue-Chartjs library. I need the Y-axis max value to change everytime the user changes the filters given. I Import an existing barchart from the vue-chartjs library. In the code there is a javascript file that has some defaults already, to set extra options I can use the extraOptions object as a prop to personalize each chart accordingly. Here is the default component:

```
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { hexToRGB } from "./utils";
import reactiveChartMixin from "./mixins/reactiveChart";

let defaultOptions = {
  tooltips: {
   tooltipFillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
   tooltipFontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",
   tooltipFontSize: 14,
   tooltipFontStyle: "normal",
   tooltipFontColor: "#fff",
   tooltipTitleFontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",
   tooltipTitleFontSize: 14,
   tooltipTitleFontStyle: "bold",
   tooltipTitleFontColor: "#fff",
   tooltipYPadding: 6,
   tooltipXPadding: 6,
   tooltipCaretSize: 8,
   tooltipCornerRadius: 6,
   tooltipXOffset: 10,
},
legend: {
  display: false
},
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      fontColor: "#9f9f9f",
      fontStyle: "bold",
      beginAtZero: true,
      display: false,
      min: 0,
      max: 100
    },
  gridLines: {
    display: false,
    drawBorder: false,
  }
}],
xAxes: [{
  gridLines: {
    display: false,
    drawBorder: false,
   },
 }],
    }
   };
     export default {
        name: 'BarChart',
        extends: Bar,
        mixins: [reactiveChartMixin],
        props: {
        labels: {
        type: [Object, Array],
        description: 'Chart labels. This is overridden when `data` is provided'
    },
    datasets: {
      type: [Object, Array],
      description: 'Chart datasets. This is overridden when `data` is provided'
    },
    data: {
      type: [Object, Array],
      description: 'Chart.js chart data (overrides all default data)'
    },
    color: {
      type: String,
      description: 'Chart color. This is overridden when `data` is provided'
    },
    extraOptions: {
      type: Object,
      description: 'Chart.js options'
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      description: 'Chart title'
    },
  },
  methods: {
    assignChartData() {
      let { gradientFill } = this.assignChartOptions(defaultOptions);
      let color = this.color || this.fallBackColor;
      return {
        labels: this.labels || [],
        datasets: this.datasets ? this.datasets : [{
          label: this.title || '',
          backgroundColor: gradientFill,
          borderColor: color,
          pointBorderColor: "#FFF",
          pointBackgroundColor: color,
          pointBorderWidth: 2,
          pointHoverRadius: 4,
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
          pointRadius: 4,
          fill: true,
          borderWidth: 1,
          data: this.data || []
        }]
      }
    },
    assignChartOptions(initialConfig) {
      let color = this.color || this.fallBackColor;
      const ctx = document.getElementById(this.chartId).getContext('2d');
      const gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 170, 0, 50);
      gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0)");
      gradientFill.addColorStop(1, hexToRGB(color, 0.6));
      let extraOptions = this.extraOptions || {}
      return {
        ...initialConfig,
        ...extraOptions,
        gradientFill
      };
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.chartData = this.assignChartData({});
    this.options = this.assignChartOptions(defaultOptions);
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options, this.extraOptions);
  }
}
```

I use this js file to import the bar chart inside a vue component like you see down below.
everytime the input of the form changes i need to re render the chart. I use the `onInputChange()` method to turn the boolean `loaded` to false and call the `loadData()` method.
Inside the `loadData()` method I make an axios request that gets me the right data every time. I also get the maximum value for my Y axis.

Then in the response I call on `updateChart()` so that I can update the data and the max value of the chart. then i turn the boolean `loaded` to true again so that my chart renders accordingly.

The problem with this approach is that the chart disappears completely for a split of a second. Before deciding to change the max Value of the Y axis I was able to update the data of my chart without having to use the v-if="loaded".

I need to find a solution where the chart re renders without it completely disappearing from the page. I know some suggested to use computed variables but i don't fully understand how it is supposed to work. Here is the component minus the form fields.

I guess in it's essence what I want is to update the Y axis max value without having to re render the entire chart.

```
 <template>
      <div>
          <BarChart v-if="loaded" :labels="chartLabels"
                 :datasets="datasets"
                 :height="100"
                 :extraOptions="extraOptions"
          >
          </BarChart>
        <br>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import BarChart from '../../components/Library/UIComponents/Charts/BarChart'
    import Dropdown from "../../components/Library/UIComponents/Dropdown"
    import GroupedMultiSelectWidget from "~/components/widgets/GroupedMultiSelectWidget"
    import SelectWidget from "../../components/widgets/SelectWidget";
    
    
    export default{
      name: 'PopularChart',
      components: {BarChart, Dropdown, SelectWidget, GroupedMultiSelectWidget},
      data(){
        return {
          loaded:true,
          form:{
              day: 'Today',
              workspace:'',
              machine_family: [],
              duration: [],
              user_group: [],
              dt_start:'',
              dt_end:''
          },
          url: `/api/data_app/job_count_by_hour/`,
          chart_data: [],
          days: [ {day:"Today", id:"Today"},
                  {day:"Monday", id:"0"},
                  {day:"Tuesday",id:"1"},
                  {day:"Wednesday",id:"2"},
                  {day:"Thursday",id:"3"},
                  {day:"Friday",id:"4"},
                  {day:"Saturday",id:"5"},
                  {day:"sunday",id:"6"} ],
          chartLabels: ["00u", "1u", "2u", "3u","4u","5u", "6u", "7u", "8u", "9u", "10u", "11u", "12u", "13u", "14u", "15u","16u", "17", "18u","19u","20u","21u","22u","23u"],
          datasets: [],
          maximumValue: '',
          extraOptions:{}
    
        }
      },
      methods: {
        onInputChange() {
          this.loaded = false
          this.loadData()
        },
        async loadData() {
            await this.$axios.get(`${this.url}?day=${this.form.day}&date_start=${this.form.dt_start}&date_end=${this.form.dt_end}&workspace=${this.form.workspace}&user_group=${this.form.user_group}&machine_family=${this.form.machine_family}`)
              .then(response => {
                this.updateChart(response.data.results,response.data.maximum)
                this.loaded = true
            })
        },
        updateChart(data,maxValue) {
            this.datasets = [{
                  label: ["jobs %"],
                  backgroundColor:"#f93232",
                  data: data
            },]
            this.maximumValue = maxValue
            this.extraOptions = {
              tooltips: {
                callbacks:{
                  label: function (tooltipItems,){
                          if (tooltipItems.value > ((50/100) * maxValue)){
                            return 'busy';
                          }else if (tooltipItems.value < ((30/ 100) * maxValue) ){
                             return ' not busy';
                          }else if ( tooltipItems.value < ((40/ 100) * maxValue )){
                            return 'kind of busy'
                          }
                      }
                }
              },
              scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  gridLines: {
                    zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false,
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    max: this.maximumValue,
                    display: true,
                  }
              }],
              xAxes: [{
                  gridLines: {
                  zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                  display: false,
                  drawBorder: false,
                  },
              }],
            },
          }
        },
    
      },
      mounted() {
        this.loadData()
      },
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provided a [mcve] (use codesandbox.io). Your snippet is not sufficient to create one with what you've shown so far (i.e.: what does reactiveChart mixin contain?). Anyway, the short answer is: create a `maxValue` prop in your instance and update it with correct value when you need to. Use a `watch: { maxValue: { handler(val) { /* update chart label*/ }}`  to update the chart label with whatever update method chart.js exposes

Comment: the reactive mixin is something that comes with the library: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts, it doesnt support my extraOptions prop that i passed, adding a watch doesnt really help sadly. I will try and look at reproducing it on sandbox, i have never used it though

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the chart to a variable in `data()`, initialize it with some defaults in `mounted()` and whenever you want to update the chart data, you use the [Chart.js API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html).

An implementation could look something like this:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      chart: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.chart = new Chart(/* defaults */);
  },
  methods: {
    updateChart(data) {
      this.chart.data.datasets = data;
      /* rest of the chart updating */
      this.chart.update();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: ive seen this quite often however, this.chart.update is not a valid function that i can use

Comment: What do you mean? If you have a `chart` variable with a Chart.js instance, it should work. And where is your `renderChart()` method in the code?

Comment: the renderchart methos you can find in the first js base chart. The second piece of code is where i import that default chart and pass the extra options as a chart. when i try to use chart.update like you say i get an error in the console saying that it is not a function.

Comment: It's not available in the code you provided. If `renderChart()` is initializing a new Chart.js instance everytime it's called, then you simply need to reuse the same instance once it's created. Sharing a working code example would be more helpful.

Comment: It is. look at the mounted() method in the first snippet of code all the way to the bottom. in there they call this.renderChart() and pass in data and options as props. i dont instatiate an instance because this is vue Chart js and it is a bit different than just chartjs. I havent written all the code myself that is why i am also having trouble understanding

Comment: Yes, I saw the call to `renderChart()`. I'm trying to find out where it's defined, to see what that function does.

Comment: well, as i can see in my project, that method is a built in method pre defined inside the vue chart js library. so not sure i should edit that method since its inside my node modules folder

Comment: Yeah, don't edit that. There is a way to update the charts according to vuejs-charts. Try if this helps: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts

Comment: yes indeed, in the section where it talks about examples/chart with API data it suggest to do what i did with the v-if statement, but that causes the chart to re render entirely causing it to disappear for a fraction of a second which is a bit annoying, hence why i am looking for another solution. but thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I've worked with Chart.js in vue, but I always used the vanilla version. I'd recommend to setup your own Chart.js component in vue using the vanilla version. I made a simple app a few years ago, you can check out the code for reference: https://github.com/butttons/reddit-trends

Comment: Thanks! indeed i think i need to just write the chart component by myself.  the component you see here was some legacy code from someone else. I will try this approach later!